# How to use CMake to link the "numpy/arrayobject.h"

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, undefined-reference

I am doing FRVT 1:1 verification. So I need to use the program provided by FRVT. I have connected to the program I wrote, and completed implementation.
But I want to transplant what I wrote in cython step by step in the `NullImp` Example provided by FRVT. But I got this result:

nullimplfrvt11.cpp

```
....
#include <Python.h>                          //(is ok)
#include "numpy/arrayobject.h" //(error)
....
```

CMakelists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

include_directories (${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../common/src/include)

# Configure built shared libraries in top-level lib directory
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib)

find_package(numpy REQUIRED)

find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})




# Build the shared libraries
add_library (frvt_11_null_001 SHARED nullimplfrvt11.cpp)
```

output:

```
[root@4d3eca5735a2 11]# bash run_validate_11.sh
Checking installation of required packages [SUCCESS]
Looking for core implementation library in /frvt/11/lib.[SUCCESS] Found core implementation library /frvt/11/lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so.
Attempting to compile and link /frvt/11/lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so against test harness.
Scanning dependencies of target validate11
[ 50%] Building CXX object src/testdriver/CMakeFiles/validate11.dir/frvt/common/src/util/util.cpp.o
[100%] Building CXX object src/testdriver/CMakeFiles/validate11.dir/validate11.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable ../../../bin/validate11
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_Format'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyCObject_AsVoidPtr'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_RuntimeError'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyObject_GetAttrString'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyExc_AttributeError'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyImport_ImportModule'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyErr_SetString'
../../../lib/libfrvt_11_null_001.so: undefined reference to `PyCObject_Type'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/validate11] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/testdriver/CMakeFiles/validate11.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
[ERROR] There were errors during compilation of your library with the validation test harness.  Please investigate and re-compile.
```

Comment: What version of CMake are you using? Please add this information to your question post.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few issues with the CMake file. The use of `find_package(PythonLibs ...)` has been deprecated since CMake 3.12. You should consider using the newer commands, such as [`find_package(Python2 ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.16/module/FindPython2.html). Also, CMake does not provide a find module specifically for NumPy, you have to specify `NumPy` as a `COMPONENT` when you call `find_package(Python2 ...)`. This way, you can use the imported target `Python2::NumPy` defined by the FindPython module to get the Numpy includes and library.

The call to `target_link_libraries()` must specify a **target** to link the libraries to. The only target defined in your CMake file is `frvt_11_null_001`, so that should be the first argument to `target_link_libraries()`. You should also prefer to use the target-specific variant of [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html) so to not pollute the CMake directory scope with include directories.

With these fixes, your CMake can look something like this.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

set (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

# Configure built shared libraries in top-level lib directory
set (CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../lib)

find_package (Python2 COMPONENTS Interpreter NumPy)

# Build the shared libraries
add_library (frvt_11_null_001 SHARED nullimplfrvt11.cpp)
target_include_directories (frvt_11_null_001 PUBLIC
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../include
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../common/src/include
)
target_link_libraries(frvt_11_null_001 PUBLIC Python2::NumPy)
```

Comment: i get the "fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory" :(

Comment: @abcinthehouse I adjusted my answer to be specific to Python2. It looked like you are using Python2 so that may work better. Although you shouldn't need it if `find_package()` worked correctly, you can try adding `${Python2_INCLUDE_DIRS}` to your directory list in `target_include_directories()`. This may help with the error.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it:

```
find_package(Python3 3.7 COMPONENTS Interpreter NumPy REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(c__14 ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} Python3::NumPy)
```

where 3.7 is your version and c__14 is the project name

Answer (score 1):

You can use `add_subdirectory()` to add numpy library in project.

> example `add_subdirectory(your/library/path)`

Comment: i link to /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy ,but still error

Comment: Follow the below link that would be helpful to you.   [ http://www.erikfrojdh.com/python/interfacing-python-numpy-from-c-part-1-3/ ]